# Does JavaScript's for in loop iterate over methods?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

In an [article](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/) on yuiblog Douglas Crockford says that the `for in` statement will iterate over the methods of an object.  Why does the following code not produce ["a", "b", "c", "d", "toString"]?  Aren't .toString() and other methods members of my_obj?

```
Object.prototype.toString = function(){return 'abc'}
Object.prototype.d = 4;

my_obj = {
    'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3
}

a = []
for (var key in my_obj) {
    a.push(key)
}

console.log(a) // prints ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All user defined properties are enumerable, including the properties inherited from prototype. The built-in native properties are not. `toString()` is one of them. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/For...in

**Edit**: My interpretation of *"However, the loop will iterate over all user-defined properties (including any which overwrite built-in properties)"* is that the properties that are overwritten directly in the object become enumerable. Not the overwrite in the prototype itself. That means:

```
var my_obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
my_obj.toString = function() {return 'abc';};

a = []
for (var key in my_obj) {
    a.push(key)
}

console.log(a) // prints ["a", "b", "c", "toString"]
```

Comment: Yep, `Object.prototype.toString.propertyIsEnumerable() == false`

Comment: From the document you linked: "A for...in loop does not iterate over built-in properties. These include all built-in methods of objects, such as String's indexOf  method or Object's toString  method. However, the loop will iterate over all user-defined properties (including any which overwrite built-in properties)."
Why does the document say that "including any which overwrite built-in properties" if in my example .toString() is not overwritten?

Answer (score 3):

`for..in` iterates over user-defined properties.  If you change your code to:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function() { return 'abc'; };
```

Then

```
console.log(a);
```

Will output:

```
["a", "b", "c", "foo", "d"]
```

As [Chetan Sastry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542341/does-javascripts-for-in-loop-iterate-over-methods/2542369#2542369) pointed pointed out, `toString` is treated differently since it is a built-in, native property.